# Problemas con Query de MYSQL A SQLSERVER

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo errores con esta consulta en **SQLSERVER**, funciona en **MYSQL**, pero ahora que migro todo a SQLSERVER tengo algunos problemas con la sintaxis. 
¿Alguien sabe una solución?

Aquí está la consulta:

```
select * from exlcartu_devcit.exl_user where username = '" .  
$this->db->escape($username) . "' and (password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, 
SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $this->db->escape($password) . "'))))) or 
password = '" . $this->db->escape(md5($password)) . "') and status = '1'
```

El problema comienza con SHA1, el error dice:

> "that it is not a built-in function".

Comment: Por que seleccione esta en español y no SELECT lo mismo con FROM que dice donde

Comment: Fijate reemplazando la función por https://www.sqlshack.com/the-hashbytes-function-in-t-sql/

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en la estructuración en `SQLServer` el `SHA1`

Ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @salt NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'salt123'
SELECT HASHBYTES ('SHA1', @salt) AS [Hash value];
```